# How to transfer clipboard content over the local network?

Tags: networking

I am working with two UNIX machines on my desk, sitting on the same local network, without a firewall.  How can I easily and instantly transfer a short amount of information from one machine to the other?

Ideally I would like to start some process `a` on machine `A` and a process `b` on machine `B` which transfers `stdin` to `a`'s `stdout`.

It seems that `netcat` would be appropriate but I could not figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what `netcat` is for.

```
tim@A % nc -l 1234
tim@B % nc A 1234
```

would do.  If you are behind a firewall and can reach `C` through `ssh` (where `C` might also be `A` or `B`), use

```
tim@A % ssh C nc -l 1234
tim@B % ssh C nc localhost 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm Using Bethclip. There is multiple platforms support. You can get them from facbook.com/bethclip

THey have public beta.

Comment: That's neat but unusable for private or sensitive content, so it is not worth considering. At least for me.